# Planning to make an application need help

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I am planning on making an application which automates some taks for me, these tasks are

getting same file from two folder, setting folder name to current date + some text, making a .zip of the folder, opening outlook and attaching that .zip file to new mail.

So can you guys advice should i make this application on windows workflows foundation or just plain c# by using .net calls. any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to learn WF, then use that as a good self-tutorial application.  Otherwise, it's not a very complicated design and it doesn't have a lot of steps or interactions, so straight C# would probably be quickest.

Comment: but will it be possible from to wpf to give call to winrar to make a zip file of this folder and for outlook to open a new mail and attach a folder to this mail if how a little hint will be welcome

Comment: If you can do it with C#, you can do it in a WF activity.  Example WinRAR C# code:  http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/process-csharp.aspx
 and eample C# emailing code:  http://www.jscape.com/articles/sending_email_using_csharp.html